# How do I indent C code generated by SymbolicC?

Tags: output-formatting, code-generation

I'm continuing to experiment with the `` SymbolicC` `` package, and it's crucial to be able to inspect the generated code in order to do, well, anything useful with it. The [`ToCCodeString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/SymbolicC/ref/ToCCodeString.html) makes this possible, but as far as I can tell, produces code with sensible line breaks but no indentation. Reading unindented code is sort of possible, but not at all fun. Is there an option to turn indentation on?

Right now, I've set things up so I can use the ["Artistic Style" package](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose, and while it looks like a pretty nice program, relying on it means one more dependency on top of Mathematica and Visual Studio.

**UPDATE** to add: I'm interested in inspecting code that I generate programmatically, and developing the program to do the generation interactively in a notebook. I'd prefer not to have to take manual steps like using `ToCCodeString` to generate the string, and then copy'n'paste it to Visual Studio to inspect it unless I really have to.

Comment: Does this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264410%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) suit your purposes?

Comment: `ToCCodeString` has the "Indent" option, which defaults to `None`. Set it to the number of tabs you want for an indentation, and you should be fine.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I can't upvote that and possibly accept it unless you post it as an answer, not a comment. :)

Comment: All right, done :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ToCCodeString` has the `"Indent"` option, which defaults to `None`. Set it to the number of tabs you want for an indentation, and you should be fine.